# Return first substring till It Matches in PHP

Tags: php, regex

i am stuck with this

I have a string let say

```
$name = 'asdf_Aadf01_2*f854?# sadf';
```

and i need

**'asdf_Aadf01_2'** in return  means *alpha numeric with underscore until a non alphanumeric and _ character found*

Comment: You need to clarify on your question more before you get wicked down votes

Comment: Why did some body negate. Plz tell the reason.so that i can improve myself

Comment: Have you tried to do anything?

Comment: @hindmost what does it mean i have gone through preg function, and i am not much aware about that that's why i asked

Comment: @Darren what more i should tell about ?

Comment: `$str = substr($name, 0, strpos($name, '*'));`

Comment: @developerCK You can't just say *`"Heres my string, how do i get what I want"`*. You need to show attempts and what you've done, you need to expand on the question, give more information.

Comment: @Darren, Ok , acutally i was not aware about preg_* functions and didn't have any direction for what should i do, so didn't want to confuse any member by posting wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
preg_match('/\w*/', $name, $match);
```

`$match[0]` will contain what you're looking for.

`\w` matches an alphanumeric or underscore character. The `*` quantifier means to match 0 or more of the preceding element.

Comment: Thanks @Barmer it works well, can u please tell me what \w* matches

Comment: Yeah, this one is good!

Comment: Matches a word character zero or more times. A word character represents case insensitive a-z0-9 and an underscore character.

Comment: Please go to regular-expressions.info to learn how regular expressions work. I'm not going to try to teach you the basics here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, but if you want something that is base on the input or something like that kindly ask me, I'll try.

```
$name = 'asdf_Aadf01_2*f854?# sadf';

$name_substr = substr($name, 0, -12);

echo $name_substr;
```